# Page Speed - Test Script response speed

Tags: php, apache, wordpress

I made a website recent and it's loading very slow. My Firebug Page Speed Score is 82/100. I think this is good. My website has 2 images and they have 100KB and some other small images for bullets, arrows and stuff that have not more that 50KB. 
Anyway, my point is that the html is quite fast, but I have this html as a Wordpress theme and a new host (cheap one).

**My question:** How can I find the time for my Wordpress (or any PHP script) to echo out the page requested.

Can I know for sure if the hosting or the script that is making my page work slow?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

time your script?

```
<?php
$start = microtime(true);

  //your script here

$end = microtime(true);
$time = $end - $start;
echo('script took ' . $time . ' seconds to execute.');
?>
```

Comment: U... so for a wordpress I need to add this start to the index of my root file, and the end, after the comment, to the template from my theme, right?

Comment: yes. where it says `//your script here` you want all the includes and requires and so forth. Ideally, you want `$start` to be the absolute first thing in your script and the `$end`, `$time` and `echo` statements to be the absolute last. This way we can accurately measure how long your script takes to load.

Comment: My WP takes 2-3 seconds to load the scrip, is that long?

Comment: it largely depends on what the script is doing.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) for this.  It is a handy tool that can accurately time the entire request and response, to and from the server.

Just open Fiddler, go to your site, select all of the requests related, and click the statistics tab.

Comment: This is showing me informations like yslow or page speed, but I think this reqest is fine, the time for the server to echo a database quesry is taking to long, and I think it`s from the host. (I don't know to debug, and I don't even know if I need to debug the php code)

Comment: @FlorescuAdrian, Fiddler shows you that.  The time from the request to the time that the server responded is that time that it takes the server to render the page.  If you want to know specifically what in your application is holding things up, you will need to profile your code.  If it is WordPress, it is safe to say that it is generally a slow application.